# cy.intercept is not matching the desired url

Tags: cypress, cy.intercept

I am trying to use cy.intercept to match a url, however it seems to be intercepting a different url. I want to intercept the API request made when I click a save button, when this button is clicked, it makes a request to these two endpoints (for example)

`POST https://api.example.com/test/foo/bar`

`POST https://api.example.com/test/foo`

I want to intercept the second call only, however, it seems like everytime, it would always intercept the first one and not the second one.
In my code, I am just doing the following:

`cy.intercept('POST', 'https://api.example.com/test/foo').as('foo');`

I have tried intercepting both the requests, but somehow it always picks catches the foo/bar endpoint instead.
Am I doing something wrong? I had assumed it would do an exact match of what I passed in the cy.intercept request.
Could it be because the request I am trying to intercept has the form-data type? Or simply because its the first request? (sounds a bit weird to me)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: For work purposes, unfortunately I am not able to share the exact code, however, its roughly like this

```
 before(() => {
    cy.intercept('POST', 'https://api.example/com/test/foo').as('foo');
    });

Given('Test bla3x 1', async () => {
    cy.get(element).click();
});

Then('test bla3x 2', async () => {
    cy.wait('@foo').then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    })
})
```

To run the tests, at the moment I am just using the normal cypress runner, and as I mentioned earlier, the result of the `console.log` is incorrect because its intercepting the `/foo/bar` url instead of `/foo`. I also forgot to mention that I am using cucumber preprocessor with cypress.... although I don't believe that's related to this issue, since I did manage to intercept some other urls.

Comment: Share your code and test runner results so we can check if the placement of the intercept along with the execution is correct.

Comment: Unfortunately due to work purposes, I'm not able to share the exact code, however I've added a snippet of it, and hopefully its sufficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [regex](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Matching-url) to match the url you want. `$` is used to match the ending of the string so you'll only spy on the `POST https://api.example.com/test/foo` call.

```js
cy.intercept('POST', /https:\/\/api.example.com\/test\/foo$/).as('foo');
```

Comment: This does work!!! Completely forgot that we can do this, thank you!!!